# How to output two dynamic variables that depend on each other

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

So for example :

Controller:

```
AllBooks[{
book1:{
hardcover{price:25.99},e-book{price:1.99}
}
},
book2:{
hardcover{price:60.00},e-book{price:2.99}
}];

$scope.bookchoice = function(selectedBook) {
$rootScope.choice = selectedBook;}


$scope.booktype = function(selectedType) {
$rootScope.type = selectedType;}
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="bookchoice(book1)">Book1</button>
<button ng-click="booktype(e-book)">E-Book</button>

{{choice.type.price}} <---this does not work
```

So I would like to know how to combine two dependent dynamic variables to access a part of an array and output the information

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Your AllBooks data is a bit weird. I am not sure if possible but I would reformat it like this. Then you can easily access the data using the key.

```
AllBooks = {
   book1:{hardcover{price:25.99},e-book{price:1.99}},
   book2:{hardcover{price:60.00},e-book{price:2.99}}
};

$scope.bookchoice = function(selectedBook) {
$rootScope.choice = AllBooks[selectedBook];}


$scope.booktype = function(selectedType) {
$rootScope.type = selectedType;}
```

You can access it like this

```
<button ng-click="bookchoice('book1')">Book1</button>
<button ng-click="booktype('e-book')">E-Book</button>

{{choice[type].price}}
```

You might want to use quotes in your ng-click methods to avoid problems.

Comment: how is AllBook data formatted? Do you generate it or u get it from the server? It has a weird format.

Comment: I copied your solution exactly and it crashed the app...I think it is a formatting issue

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$scope.allBooks = { 
    book1: {
        hardcover: {
            price: 25.99
        },
        e_book: {
            price: 1.99
        }
    }, 
    book2: {
        hardcover: {
            price: 60.00
        },
        e_book: {
            price: 2.99
        }
    }
} ;

$scope.bookchoice = function ( selectedBook ) {
    $rootScope.choice = selectedBook;
}

$scope.booktype = function ( selectedType ) {
    $rootScope.choice.type = selectedType;
}
```

HTML

```
<button ng-click="bookchoice(allBooks.book1)">Book1</button>
<button ng-click="bookchoice(allBooks.book2)">Book2</button>
<button ng-click="booktype(choice.e_book)">E-Book</button>
<button ng-click="booktype(choice.hardcover)">Hardcover</button>

{{choice.type.price}}
```